# Spring Data JPA: CriteriaQuery to get entities with max value for each unique foreign key

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

There's an `Event` class:

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Company company;

    @Column
    private Long time;

    ...

}
```

I want to have an `EventFilter` class (implementing `Specification`) which will produce `CriteriaQuery` to select entities the same way as the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM events e1
WHERE e1.time = (
    SELECT MAX(time)
    FROM events e2
    WHERE e1.company_id = c2.company_id
)
```

Filtered result will contain only events with unique `Company` and max `time` value per company.

This is the `EventFilter` class with what I ended up with:

```
public class EventFilter implements Specification<Event> {

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Event> root, CriteriaQuery<?> q, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        Subquery<Long> subquery = q.subquery(Long.class);
        Root<Event> subRoot = subquery.from(Event.class);
        subquery.select(cb.max(root.get("time")))
                .where(cb.equal(root.get("company"), subRoot.get("company")));
        return cb.equal(root.get("time"), subquery);
    }

}
```

When `EventRepository#findAll(EventFilter filter)` is called, results are not filtered at all. Please help me to implement this logic correctly.

Comment: How does the SQL statement look like that is generated with this filter?

Comment: And why do you call super.toPredicate ? you should return a predicate using the CriteriaBuilder instead.

Comment: I have corrected the code

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, thanks for advice! Inspecting generated SQL solved the problem!

Answer (score 4):

After inspecting SQL statement generated by Hibernate I've found an error: `root` was used instead of `subRoot`. The correct method body is:

```
Subquery<Long> sub = q.subquery(Long.class);     
Root<Event> subRoot = sub.from(Event.class);     
sub.select(cb.max(subRoot.get("time")))
   .where(cb.equal(root.get("company"), subRoot.get("company")));
return cb.equal(root.get("time"), sub);
```